# Lock screen turn off and on : Goes to a loop asking to enter password to unlock- then turns off again.

Tags: 12.10, password, monitor, login-screen, lock-screen

I recently updated my laptop from 12.04 to 12.10. And now, whenever I lock screen with "CTRL+ALT+L", the screen locks, and monitor turns off. But within 30 seconds, it turns on and asks for password. After some time, it says 'Time expired' and turns off. This keeps happening until my battery goes dead. :-1

Please assist me with this.

Also, I'm using Dell Inspiron 15R (5520) (no external graphics card). Often the fan speed goes very high for sometime. If you have any solution, please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes applications like ktorrent or certain media players have a setting to prevent the computer from going to sleep. They can sometimes even interfere with the screen lock.

Try closing these apps if running in the background, and if it works, try searching for such settings and change it to suite your needs.

For example in VLC, the setting is under-

`Tools` > `Preferences` > set options to `Show All` > `Advanced` > `Inhibit the power management daemon...` checkbox

Just clear it and check if it works.